# Update multiple objects in a class with one call in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, cloud

I am starting to use parse.com and are satisfied so far but am running into an issue. I have a class, friends, in which I have over 10.000 objects. Now, I have just added a new number column to this class and all the fields in that column writes: (undefined)

Is it possible to set a default value in all of them like you do with mysqli and:

```
UPDATE table SET newcolumn=5
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: No. It's not. You'll need to write some sort of migration function to query, update, and save the required value in the new column. My advice would be to create a cloud based background job, where you query out a batch of objects where the new column is undefined, update them, and save them in batch again. It's a pain that Parse.com doesn't have batch data editing facilities in the UI.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Is it then possible to see if an field is undefined. Is there anyway, in Unity C#, to make a "if(field == "undefined"){" and then do something? Btw, the example written does not do the job :-/